# Inserir múltiplos Markers no Maps

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment, google-maps-android-api-2

Achei um código aqui no site, coloquei em meu projeto porém não funcionou, alguém sabe como posso resolver? O método abaixo é chamado no `onViewCreated()`

Obs: Estou usando o Mapa dentro de um fragment, pode ser isso?

```
public class MapsFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

GoogleMap gMap;
private LatLng latLng;
private Marker marker;
private MarkerOptions markerOptions;
Onibus onibus = new Onibus();

public MapsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    pedirPermissao();
    carregarLocalizacoes();
}

public void carregarLocalizacoes() {

    ArrayList<LatLng> locations = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    locations.add(new LatLng(-12.833291, -38.377971));
    locations.add(new LatLng(-12.824711, -38.390898));
    locations.add(new LatLng(-12.795636, -38.404648));

    for (LatLng location : locations) {

        if (location != null) {

            markerOptions.position(location);
            markerOptions.title(onibus.getRoteiro());
            gMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }

    }

}
```

O erro que aparece é o seguinte:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions.position(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng)' on a null object reference

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow Elailson. Coloque o link para a pergunta/resposta de onde você copiou o código. Onde você inicializa a variável `markerOptions`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30569854/adding-multiple-markers-in-google-maps-api-v2-android

Comment: A variável é inicializada logo abaixo da linha de criação da classe.

Comment: Seria bom colocar essa parte do código também na pergunta, então, porque parece ser esse o problema.

Comment: Inseri, mas acredito que não seja esse o problema. A linha que acusa o erro é a: markerOptions.position(location);

Comment: Sim, mas dá erro nessa linha porque você tenta usar o objeto que está armazenado na variável `markerOptions`, mas a variável não faz referência a nenhum objeto. Veja a resposta do Lucas.

Answer (score 1):

Você apenas definiu que o markerOptions é um objeto do tipo `MarkerOptions`, você precisa instanciar antes de fazer qualquer operação com o mesmo.

**Exemplo:**

```
if (location != null) {
      markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
      markerOptions.position(location);
      markerOptions.title(onibus.getRoteiro());
      gMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
}
```

Comment: Fiz a alteração, porém ainda não funcionou :/

Comment: É sempre bom você informar o log do erro. Bota aqui pra eu pode lhe ajudar

Comment: Agora o erro foi para a ultima linha (gMap.addMarker(markerOptions);).

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference

Comment: @ElailsonSilva, é porque você também não carregou a variável `gMap` com nenhum objeto, ela está vazia.

Comment: Como faço para carrega-la? Está pedido um parâmetro, não sei qual é.

Comment: Em outro trecho do código, eu consigo usar a variável gMap sem problemas, usando a instância feita logo no inicio do código.

Comment: Então posta essa parte do código em que a `gMap` funciona, porque nessa classe que você postou a variável é definida mas nenhum objeto é carregado nela.

Comment: @Elailson Silva, me parece você precisa estudar um pouco mais sobre POO, recomendo você da uma lida nesse link: [apostila-java-orientacao-objetos](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/orientacao-a-objetos-basica/#criando-um-tipo). Para sanar essa sua dúvida eu recomendo você ler os seguintes tópicos desse link: 

**4.2 Criando um tipo;**
**4.3 Uma classe em Java;**
**4.4 Criando e usando um objeto;**
**4.5 Métodos;**
**4.6 Métodos com retorno.**

Poste o código especifico que funciona para a gente dar uma olhada.

Comment: Uma outra coisa que é sempre bom fazer... Sempre que tiver dúvidas procure pela documentação ela é bem mais esclarecedora e bastante rica em conteúdo.

[documentação](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map-with-marker)

Comment: Outra coisa que vai sempre lhe ajudar é que eles costumam botar seus códigos de exemplo no github e la você pode ver toda a estrutura do projeto que foi desenvolvido. [GitHub](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples)

Comment: Observando o **GitHub** deles, você vai ver que é possível pegar a Instância do `gMap`, ou melhor dizendo o GoogleMap, em:
`public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)`

Comment: Olha ai: [Exemplo](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/tutorials/MapWithMarker/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapwithmarker/MapsMarkerActivity.java)